# How do I put a couple of elements inside template?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js

I need to create templates in handlebars for an html page and the whole html should go inside of templates. For e.g. I have:

```
    <div class= "something-pull-left-something">
      <div class="someclass">
      <li a href= ''>Some more info and some more divs and spans and html code</li>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and I should create a big template for the first div ''something-pull-left-something'' and smaller templates inside of it for the other items and I cant quite understand how this should happen.

Answer (score 0):

Divide it up into parts as it makes sense. Try to avoid having one huge template. Instead, make one template that includes a number of other templates. You may run into performance issues but worry about that later -- it is likely not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make main template which contains header, body and footer.
2. Add partials to the main template.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to use Bootstrap then you can go through this http://getbootstrap.com/components

or you can use bootstrap class

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   //code 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        //code 
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        //code
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```